# missing ) after argument list in EJS Expess API

Tags: javascript, api, express, ejs

[image]I am getting data from an api and sending it to home.ejs file and displaying it.I get this error after I include the line:

```
<p><%= data[i].blocks.requestedBodyBlocks.body:latest:1[0].bodyHtml %></p>
```

The api is providing the data properly because when I run the requested url on google it works fine.
Please help.

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\NEWS\views\home.ejs while compiling ejs.
```

home.ejs

```
<%- include('header') %>
<div id="news">
<% for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ %>
<div id="post">
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<%= i%>" aria-expanded="false">
    <p><%=data[i].webTitle%></p>
    <p><%=data[i].fields.trailText %></p>
    <p><%=data[i].fields.byline %></p>
    <p><%=data[i].webPublicationDate %></p>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse<%= i%>" >
    <div class="card card-body">
        <p><img src=<%= data[i].fields.thumbnail %> ></p>
        <p>Bodyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</p>
        <p><%= data[i].blocks.requestedBodyBlocks.body:latest:1[0].bodyHtml %></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: `.body:latest:1[0]` is not valid js

Comment: But that is how the api is given.What can I do to make it valid?

Comment: Post the contents of `data[i].blocks.requestedBodyBlocks.body` in your question

Comment: This the api request:http://content.guardianapis.com/search?order-by=newest&show-fields=trailText,title,byline,thumbnail&show-blocks=body:latest:1&q=politics&api-key=eaa89d87-e540-473f-9d54-753b331a90a6 .This is the api link.It has a attribute called body:latest:1 in the data that is returned.

Comment: I added a picture to my question

Comment: First of all try to add a space before the `%>`.

Comment: I added spaces.I am still getting same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have colons `:` in your json object's keys (or characters which are valid tokens in JS, like `-`, `&`, etc.), you need to use the `["keyname"]` notation.

In your case, it would be:

```
 data[i].blocks.requestedBodyBlocks["body:latest:1"][0].bodyHtml
```